# Getting mouse position on rotated canvas in WPF/C#

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, mouse, transform

Normally I can get mouse position on WPF canvas after transformations in **TransformGroup** object. But now i need to get relative mouse position on canvas. Example [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uojsX.png) (sorry, cannot post images beacuse of reputation).

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

With access to the `TransformGroup` you can fetch the [`Matrix`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.media.matrix(v=vs.110).aspx) that is stored in the [`Value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.media.transformgroup.value(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the `TransformGroup`.

The matrix gives you the [`Transform`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms607598(v=vs.110).aspx) method to transform a point.